# How to sort a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r

Please find attached my sample [data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzAdUEYQ_mf1qivOQtzIoDcdj8KNvJw5/view?usp=sharing).

What I really want to achieve with this is to create a data frame that first sorts the data based on period on ascending order and within each period that data is sorted again by the descending order of count of case (grouped by period,region,manager,employee)

So far, I have done up to this but it does not give me what I want.

I am planning to plot this values, so that's why I need to sort it on ascending order first and within each of that I want the data to be sorted in descending order.

```
SampleRADN <- read_excel("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Exercises/PBIR/SampleRADN.xlsx")
df1<-unique(data.frame(SampleRADN))
library(dplyr)
df2<-df1%>%count(period,region,manager,employee)
df3<-df2[order(df2$period, -df2$n)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))`. Links might break in the future and/or not everyone might have access to Drive.

Comment: `df3 <- df2 %>% arrange(period, -n)`?

Comment: Please, let us know how you want to plot the values. I am not sure if it is sufficient to order the underlying data frame to achieve the desired plot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NelsonGon thank you very much for pointing out that the users need to provide the data in a better way so that the whoever is looking for a solution can always both access the data and answer. I honestly did not think of that. However, my sample data has more than 600+ rows and I don't know how to replicate the sample data of this size other than providing it through a link.
However, I solved this problem by doing following

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/smpao1/Documents/Exercises/PBIR/SampleRADN.xlsx")
df1<-data.frame(df)
df2<-df1%>%count(period,region)
df3<-df2[order(df2$period, -df2$n),]
df4<-df1%>%count(period,region,manager,employee)
df5<-df4[order(df4$period, -df4$n),]
df6<-left_join(df3,df5,by=c("period"="period","region"="region"))
df7<-df6%>% select(period, region, manager, employee,n.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to sort the data by ascending period and within each period by the descending order of count of case (grouped by period, region, manager, employee).

The solution in [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348095/3817004) is way too complicated. My suggestion is to add the group counts to the data frame and sort by period and count.

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- readxl::read_xlsx("SampleRADN.xlsx") %>%  
  add_count(period, region, manager, employee, name = "count") %>%
  arrange(period, -count)
df2
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 369 x 6
>    region  period manager employee case      count
>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <int>
>  1 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-467     12
>  2 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-591     12
>  3 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-1009    12
>  4 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-1747    12
>  5 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-2536    12
>  6 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-2579    12
>  7 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-683     12
>  8 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-1127    12
>  9 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-1748    12
> 10 Eastern      1 RP      DL       2019-1749    12
> # ... with 359 more rows
> ```

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df <- readxl::read_xlsx("SampleRADN.xlsx")
setDT(df)[, count := .N, by = .(period, region, manager, employee)]
setorder(df, period, -count)
df
```

> ```
>       region period manager employee       case count
>   1: Eastern      1      RP       DL   2019-467    12
>   2: Eastern      1      RP       DL   2019-591    12
>   3: Eastern      1      RP       DL  2019-1009    12
>   4: Eastern      1      RP       DL  2019-1747    12
>   5: Eastern      1      RP       DL  2019-2536    12
>  ---                                                 
> 365: Central      6      TG       RK 2019-28005     1
> 366: Central      6      EL       MP 2019-28363     1
> 367: Central      6      SS       DC 2019-29488     1
> 368: Central      6      JT       LV 2019-30283     1
> 369: Central      6      KJ       SL 2019-27948     1
> ```